# Solution to Producer Consumer

Tags: c, process, operating-system, infinite-loop

I am new to Operating System,I'm not getting the solution to Producer Consumer problem,
The Producer process is given as

```
item nextProduced;
while(true)
{
    while(((in+1)%BUFFER_SIZE)==out)
        ;   /* do nothing */
    buffer[in]=nextProduced;
    in=(in+1)% BUFFER_SIZE;
}
```

and the consumer process is given by-

```
item nextConsumed;
while(true)
{
    while(in==out)
        ;   /* do nothing */
    nextConsumed=buffer[out];
    out=(out+1)% BUFFER_SIZE;
}
```

What I am not getting is-
It is written in the book that in case of bounded buffer,the Consumer must wait if the buffer is empty and the producer must wait if the buffer is full,
but from the processes given above,
if the buffer is full then the condition of the second while loop will be true,and hence the process will get into an infinite loop and will not come out,then how is this solution going to work.
Someone please explain,if you may please give a practical example then that would be great!

Comment: Post declaration of `in` and `out`.

Answer (score 0):

The producer could call yield() to give the scheduler a hint that it is waiting for another thread. Else the code must be relying on preemption or multi core architecture.